# How to design the following custom UI headline with ReactJS, CSS and bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I want to develop the following type of design in a responsive in ReactJS using  Bootstrap or CSS(if necessary). This is not a header. How should I put the separators between each column and make the values of each label in the next line in the same column?
I need to have it equally spaced and should be responsive in a way when I resize the browser window it should not overflow. All the items are left aligned in each column.

My Sandbox Code -

[image: Edit runtime-sunset-2t7yyz]

The UI Design -
[image: Design]

Comment: The "separators" could be simply a `border-left`.  Flexbox will make your life easier on this problem. However a CSS Grid would too.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained and not rely solely on external links for information. Please provide a [mre] within your question.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel I have attached my sandbox code in the question above already. I saw many posts on StackOverflow that had CodeSandbox links so I did the same. Going forward I won't attach sandbox codes and I will attach it in the question I guess

Comment: That is not sufficient, as I said, questions must be self-contained. Having things like CodeSandbox is nice to have, but it is still an external link, and if CodeSandbox goes offline, or your code gets deleted there for some reason, your question is meaningless. That is the reason for the requirement that questions must be self-contained, and that means the [mre] must be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bootstrap css and custom css

```
<div className="bg-opacity-100 bg-light border" style={{paddingTop:10, paddingBottom:10}}>
      <div className="col-1"/>
      <div className="row col-11 border p-2 border bg-opacity-10 w-100" style={{marginLeft:10}}>
        <div className="col-3 text-start">
          <div className="text-muted" style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
            Order Number
          </div>
          <div style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>12345</div>
        </div>
        <div className="border-start col-3 text-start">
          <div className="text-muted" style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
            Order Name
          </div>
          <div style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>12345</div>
        </div>
        <div className="border-start col-3 text-start">
          <div className="text-muted" style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
            Country
          </div>
          <div style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>12345</div>
        </div>
        <div className="border-start col-3 text-start">
          <div className="text-muted" style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
            Price
          </div>
          <div style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>12345</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

do more CSS by yourself. Thank you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.left {
  padding-inline: 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>OrderNumber</p>
    <p>12345</p>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <p>OrderName</p>
    <p>Tesla Car</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>CarPrice</p>
    <p>CarPrice</p>
  </div>
</div>
```